# Trigger click on embedded PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I have a PDF embedded in a web page using the following code:

```
<object id="pdfviewer" data='test_full.pdf#page=1&toolbar=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&navpanes=0' 
        type='application/pdf' 
        width='500px' 
        height='350px'>
```

The PDF itself is set to open in full screen mode which shows no controls. The user can advance the slides by clicking on the view.

What I'd like to have is some way to trigger that click so that I can advance 2 similar PDF:s side-by-side (one for the actual slideshow and one for the speaker notes). Is this possible to do in javascript and/or jQuery? I have tried using the click()-method but it doesn't get through to the embedded PDF.

*Update*: Can't find any info on it, so I guess I'm out of luck and have to try a workaround. Am currently juggling 3 embeds of the same pdf (current page, next page and previous page), hiding and showing them and loading more pages as the user clicks around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it. Allowing web page scripts to pass input events to the PDF viewer could be a security risk (since the viewer generally has access to system file dialogues via things like Save As).

Comment: You're probably right. .print() on the object works, but that always comes with a dialog.